# How to change the hover color of datalist in HTML5?

Tags: html, datalist

I tried my maximum to findout the styles for hover coloring datalist. I can't find out the solution yet. Please if anyone know, reply me.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="productname">Product</label>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control custom-select productdtlst" id="productdtlst_1" name="productdtlst[]" list="productlist_1" tabindex="4" pname="" pcode="" mqty="" stock="" ptype="" ptypeoption="" ctype="" pid="">
<datalist id="productlist_1" class="hovercoloring">
<option pname="Lithium Polymer " pcode="LPBAT01" mqty="1" stock="500" ptype="fixed" ptypeoption="null" ctype="configurable" pid="5ef39a5424811227b09e403a" value="Lithium Polymer "></option>
<option pname="LGSD Cooker" pcode="LGSDC01" mqty="1" stock="500" ptype="fixed" ptypeoption="null" ctype="configurable" pid="5ef39c0faf7d2b0e8cb1b3fc" value="LGSD Cooker"></option>
<option pname="Shampoo" pcode="SHA123" mqty="1" stock="500" ptype="fixed" ptypeoption="null" ctype="configurable" pid="5f0c3cd569ab4d16807d217a" value="Shampoo"></option>
</datalist>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W3Schools always has a great resources, you didn't provide any code on how you are trying to implement hover coloring but the easiest way to do it is with CSS.

```
.hovercoloring:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

As for hover coloring a datalist you could implement it via class tags.

```
<label for="browser">Choose your browser from the list:</label>
<input list="browsers" name="browser" id="browser">

<datalist id="browsers" class="hovercoloring">
  <option value="Edge">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Hi Tanner, Thanks for the reply. I tried but the CSS is not working,. I have updated my coding.

Comment: Are you using anything that is overwriting CSS?  Like bootstrap?  Or JS or JQ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45051787/how-to-give-hover-effect-to-datalist

Try this link and see if it helps you out.

Comment: Css does not work for datalist

Answer (score 0):

Browser defines its own style for the datalist. You have little or no flexibility in styling the inbuilt datalist with your own css. Browser can also change the implementation style in future releases. Better to use a different library which uses search and select to implement its own datalist.